# How to get unique id's data among the same score

Tags: sql

The records in the table likes:

```
user           score             label
----------------------------------------------
userA            2               apple
userA            2               banana
userB            5               cat
userB            5               dog
```

For different rows, if the user and score are same, it just need to get the unique user and score, and any label is fine.

The expected query result from above is example can be any one as below:

```
user           score             label
----------------------------------------------
userA            2               apple
userB            5               cat
```

or

```
user           score             label
----------------------------------------------
userA            2               banana
userB            5               cat
```

or

```
user           score             label
----------------------------------------------
userA            2               apple
userB            5               dog
```

or

```
    user           score             label
  ----------------------------------------------
    userA            2               banana
    userB            5               dog
```

Comment: tag your database as well.

Answer (score 1):

if *any label is fine*, I think the easiest way is to use an aggregation function like min or max --

```sql
SELECT user, score, max(label) as label
FROM table
GROUP BY user, score
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use window function:

```
select * from 
( 
  select * , row_number() over (partition by user,score order by label) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1;
```